# The Insert statement conflict with the foreign key constraint. Entity Framework error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to create an one to many relation, where a TypeOfImmobile can have one Immobile or more. 
Here's my model classes :

```
public class TypeOfImmobile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Type Of Immobile")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Immobile> Immobiles { get; set; }
}

public class Immobile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeOfImmobileId { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeOfImmobile TypeOfImmobile { get; set; }
}
```

Error occurred when I create an Immobile:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Immobiles_dbo.TypeOfImmobiles_TypeOfImmobilesId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-ARQSI-IT2-20151031052056", table "dbo.TypeOfImmobiles", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: `public virtual ICollection<Immobile> Immobiles { get; set; }` maybe you missed `virtual`

Comment: I tried virtual it doesn't work :/

Comment: How exactly did you create an Immobile? Could you show us the code?

Comment: If you still need an answer you should show the code that causes the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Type of your `TypeOfImmobileId` property is `int`, so you can't set it as `null`. Even you don't assign a value to an `integer`, it would be equal to `0` not `null`. If you didn't assign a value for `TypeOfImmobileId` when your create command was sent to SQL, SQL will take it as `0` in stored procedure that create the record. And probably TypeOfImmobile table doesn't contain a record with a `0` value in its primary key. In other words, value of foreign key of the data you sent is invalid. It doesn't correspond any primary key value in TypeOfImmobile table. Your primary key should not be nullable, but foreign key should be nullable.

You should change type of `TypeOfImmobileId` from `int` to `Nullable<int>` or simply `int?`.

So `TypeOfImmobileId` property should be like this:

```
public int? TypeOfImmobileId { get; set; }
```

You don't need to add `ForeignKey` attribute to `TypeOfImmobileId` property because you follow [Code-First conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx#conventions-for-one-to-many-ef6) and [name of Foreign Key matches with name of Primary Key of related entity](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

You can observe the problem as running SQL Server Profiler. When application runs the command that will create the record, related stored procedure will be listed.

Comment: Hi, great you're joining us in the Entity Framework tag. One little tip though. Usually it's a pretty hopeless operation to answer unclear questions. The question is unclear because it doesn't show the code that causes the exception. I don't think the FK should be nullable. We really need to see the code to tell what's wrong.

Comment: It helped to me Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you are creating your `Immobile` you are probably not setting the `TypeOfImmobileId` property with a valid value, that is, the `Id` of an existing `TypeOfImmobile`.

Answer (score 0):

this causes by one of following reasons:

1-You don't set navigation property (TypeOfImmobile) or TypeOfImmobileId

2-The value of TypeOfImmobileId or TypeOfImmobile is not exist in database

3-Maybe you are saving Immobile before saving TypeOfImmobile

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the FK by `[ForeignKey("Your_FK_ImmobileId")]` in a new property id Your_FK_ImmobileId